# When are Flask Resources created?

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to  Flask. I have a resource class that handles POST requests. The request processing is quite elaborate, and can't be all in the `post` function. Do I get a new Resource instance for each request? Or are instances reused? Is it safe for me to do something like:

```
class MyResource(Resource):
    def post(self):
        self.var = 17
        self.do_some_work()
        return self.var * self.var
```

Does Flask guarantee that my resource instance will not be used for other transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource objects are created at the time the request should be served and they are not persistent. Keep in mind that REST principles say that APIs must be [stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Statelessness). If you want to store data between requests, you should use some kind of database.

The simplest method to prove what I said is to use a `print (id(self))` in your get handler and trigger the request a few times. You will see that the object always changes.

Now, if you are interested about **Flask internals**, here we go.
The class **Resource** is part of [Flask-RESTtful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the documentation states the following:

> Resources are built on top of Flask pluggable views, giving you easy access to multiple HTTP methods just by defining methods on your resource.

Resources are  added with the method [Resource.add_resource()](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L358) and it is simply registering the underlying [View](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/views/) object.

```py
if self.app is not None:
    self._register_view(self.app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
else:
    self.resources.append((resource, urls, kwargs))
```

[Resource._register_view()](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L416) method does a lot of crazy stuff, but the most meaningful things are those two lines:

```py
resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint, *resource_class_args, **resource_class_kwargs))
...
self.blueprint_setup.add_url_rule(url, view_func=resource_func, **kwargs)
```

Here you can see that the view object provides a handler that will be associated with the URL path. This handler will be called every time a HTTP request is made to this route.

Finally, we arrived at the core, in the [View.as_view()](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/views.py#L77) method, it creates a function on-the-fly and this function will represent the route handler.

```py
def view(*args, **kwargs):
    self = view.view_class(*class_args, **class_kwargs)
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, this function will create a new object every time a request must be dispatched and as you already guessed, `view_class` is containing your custom class for handling the requests.

Comment: Great, thanks. I just want to store request-specific data, that can die with the request, so I do not need any database.